# Istio custom Gateway in a namespace

Tags: kubernetes, istio, envoyproxy

I'm trying to expose a Service with Istio Gateway and VirtualService following instructions at https://istio.io/blog/2019/custom-ingress-gateway

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: demo
  name: demo
  namespace: demo
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: demo
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: demo
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: nginx
        name: nginx
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    app: demo
  name: demo
  namespace: demo
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: demo
  type: ClusterIP
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: demo-gw
  namespace: demo
spec:
  selector:
    app: demo
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "example.com"
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: demo-vs
  namespace: demo
spec:
  hosts:
  - "example.com"
  gateways:
  - demo-gw
  http:
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: demo
```

I'm running a `minikube` cluster with `minikube tunnel` so that `istio-ingressgateway` has a `LoadBalancer` IP. I've modified `/etc/hosts` to point `example.com` to `istio-ingressgateway` Service IP like so

```
10.111.251.46 example.com
```

The request does seem to reach Envoy proxy. `curl -v -X TRACE http://example.com` returns

```
*   Trying 10.111.251.46...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to example.com (10.111.251.46) port 80 (#0)
> TRACE / HTTP/1.1
> Host: example.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< date: Wed, 29 Apr 2020 12:32:49 GMT
< server: istio-envoy
< content-length: 0
< 
* Connection #0 to host example.com left intact
* Closing connection 0
```

Comment: Hi, the blog post You linked is outdated. `This blog post was written assuming Istio 1, so some of this content may now be outdated.` What Istio version do You have on Your minikube cluster?

Comment: Im running Istio 1.5 on Kubernetes 1.18, minikube 1.9.1

Answer (score 0):

As @Piotr Malec mentioned in comments

> The blog post You linked is outdated. This blog post was written assuming Istio 1, so some of this content may now be outdated.

---

I would recommend to use [istio operator](https://istio.io/blog/2019/introducing-istio-operator/), since istio 1.5 that's the best option to add your custom ingress gateway.

There is open [github issue](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/19263) about that, there are few ways to install it.

For example, with yaml from this [comment](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/19263#issuecomment-609094185) you can install istio default profile with default ingress gateway and additionally it will create second ingress gateway in namespace dev.

---

Hope you find this useful.